# subprocess.run failing to execute git command with var=value prefix but os.system does it without issue

Tags: python, git, subprocess, git-clone, python-os

I'm running into a bit of a weird issue here.

I'm trying to clone some GitHub repositories automatically but I'm seeing `subprocess.run` error out in cases where `os.system`, or just running the command directly in my shell, works fine.

This is the command I'm trying to run:

```py
subprocess.run('GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone https://github.com/fake-user/fake-repo.git'.split())
```

Which leads to this error:

```
>>> subprocess.run('GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone https://github.com/fake-user/fake-repo.git'.split())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/omermikhailk/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 546, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/omermikhailk/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/omermikhailk/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1899, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0'
```

When the result should be what `os.system` gives:

```py
>>> os.system('GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone https://github.com/fake-user/fake-repo.git')
Cloning into 'fake-repo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
32768
```

Would anyone happen to know the reason behind this?

Comment: Using `split()` is a bad idea. If you're going to use a shell, use `shell=True` to get a _real_ shell, including features like environment variable assignment (which is the specific feature your code depended on here). If you're going to specify an argv array, specify it _as an array_ -- you get more control that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following instead:

```
subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/fake-user/fake-repo.git'], env={'GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT': '0'})
```

When you run a command via subprocess, you are not using `bash` or `sh` or any shell, so environment variables are not interpreted, and must be specified via `env`, not the CLI.

Note that it is the best practice to explicitly craft the list for the command and its arguments yourself, rather than using a string and `.split()`.  If you have any arguments that contain spaces, rather than including literal quotes in the string that you pass as a list element, you would use a string that contains the full argument.  I.e., NOT `['echo', '"foo', 'bar"']` (which would be the result of `.split()`), but `['echo', 'foo bar']` to include the space.

Another note as to why this occurs is that [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) does technically allow you to pass `shell=True`, but you should avoid doing so at all costs due to security implications if you are working with any content that may be user-generated.  The best practice is to use `env={...}` as suggested.

If you need to include current environment variables, then you can use the following:

```
from os import environ

env = environ.copy()
env['GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT'] = '0'

subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/fake-user/fake-repo.git'], env=env)
```

Comment: As a note, `env=` replaces current environment so one needs to be sure all relevant environment variables are included.